# Whats the best way to light up a scene in unity?

Tags: unity, post-processing, bloom

What I want is a darkish scene with like neon style lights

Currently is use the bloom post processing effect but sometimes it doesn't render well on my main camera and looks not as good as it does in the scene

[image: Currently is use the post processing bloom effect]

My game view with main camera -
[image]

My aim is to get the lighting similar to look like [Brackeys party killer game](https://brackeysgames.itch.io/party-killer)

How may I achieve this

Comment: Have you tried setting environment light in Window>rendering>Light settings?

Comment: ill try it but is there anyway to not use the bloom filter and just have like lights in the floor